# html send as a form value displaying as text

Tags: php, html, forms

I am posting form data through a form and then having it display in another page. It works perfectly, but if I try to put html into the form where the text would go, the markup is echo'ed as text and NOT as a command.

In this example I would like to have line breaks sent along with the text so that it is easier to read and understand. I tried uni-code as well, both display

```
<br>
```

and don't  show the space instead.

```
<input type="hidden" name="my-item-name" value="Memory Upgrade <br> 36GB to 72GB<br>
to 96GB<br> to 144GB" />
```

Here is where the input is echoed out.

```
echo tab(7) . "<input type='hidden' id='jcartItempartnumber-{$item['id']}'
name='jcartItempartnumber[]' value='{$item['partnumber']}' />\n";
```

Thanks in advance. I'm sure this is just a monday lapse in common sense. My google-fu is failing me right now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `url_encode` .
for your input it will something like this :

```
Memory%20Upgrade%20%3Cbr%3E%2036GB%20to%2072GB%3Cbr%3E%0Ato%2096GB%3Cbr%3E%20to%20144GB
```

and in php file you can decode the input with this function :

```
urldecode ($str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the br tags to behave like br tags when you echo them. You example code is a little confusing, but I would try getting rid of the single quotes around some of your output values, like this:

```
 echo tab(7) . "<input type='hidden' id='jcartItempartnumber-"
 . $item['id'] ."'" .
 "name='jcartItempartnumber[]' value='" .
 $item['partnumber'] . " />\n";
```